# How to scroll to bottom in an ionic-content

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

We are working on a mobile application for iPad with Ionic v1.3.1.

In one of our pages there is an ul element at the bottom of an ion-content.

When we open the list by clicking on the ul element, the list opens and the height of the ion-content is changed but the content don't scrolls down so we can't see the open list as long as we don't scroll down manually.

We tried to scroll down to the bottom of the content by the follwing code.

The code gets the content correctly but scrollToBottom doesn't scroll to the bottom.

```
var element = document.getElementById("myContent");
if (element){
    element.content.scrollToBottom();
}
```

The content is defined in the page as this:

```
<ion-content id="myContent" class="padding has-header" scroll="true" style="overflow: scroll;">
```

Does anybody know what to do to make it work?
Any help would be appreciated.

Patrick

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Hi Sivaramakrishnan. Yes i got an error message in the console which says that content of the found element is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES2015/ES6 Style ScrollToBottom

```
import {ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';
import {Page,Content} from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({  
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/page1/page1.html',
  queries: {
      content: new ViewChild(Content)
  }
})
export class Page1 {
     constructor() {
     }
     scrollToBottom(){
        let dimensions = this.content.getContentDimensions();
        this.content.scrollTo(0, dimensions.scrollBottom, 0);
    }
}
```

You might need to add:

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that.